# Infosec Graduate - Job Title

Tags: academia

I am writing my resume for applying for jobs in Infosec - what sorts of 'job titles' should I be putting onto my resume? 'Infosec Graduate' doesn't quite sit right for me.  I am more than a graduate, I am employable, and I want to show that on my Resume.  Any advice?

Comment: Not sure what you mean... If you haven't worked anywhere, don't put job titles, because that would be insane. If you have worked somewhere before, use the title for the position in the original job posting, or a title which accurately reflects your relation to the company. If you have pertinent skills, put them on the resume. If you are looking for a particular kind of work, spell out what work that would be in the "objective" portion. In any case, I don't think this question is strictly on topic for this site.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  AN objective statment is a good way to describe what I am after really.  Just need it to be short and to the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excellent! Your resume should highlight what you have accomplished.  That is the hard part, I know.  It is important to use declarative statements which detail your biggest successes.  Most if not all of your competition will be using iterative statements which will obscure what they have done.

You should tailor your 'title' according to the job you are applying for.  If you are going into network security, governance or want to be a generalist then make sure you tilt your resume in those directions.  If you have someone help you write your resume, make sure they have had success doing what you are trying to do.

I think you have an uphill battle, but it is not insurmountable.  An infosec graduate would have to be an outstanding talent for me personally. I believe a security analyst/engineer should have gained some practical experience in software engineering, system engineering and/or network engineering first.

With your degree program, how much data science did they go through?  If you don't want monitoring tools to be a terminal position, if your place of employment has a BI department, I would buddy up with the sharpest mind there.  There are more similarities between information security and data warehousing that most IT professionals realize.

Good hunting. (Oh and go to local security conferences and join groups if you can.  The goal is to expand your network and get the interview before you give the resume).  It also gives you a good chance to practice your interfacing, a lot of your time will be explaining your viewpoint and you will be challenged often, especially as you try to change corporate culture from the way it's always been done to the way it should be done.  That is a major part of the reason that I think it would be more beneficial to earn your stripes through infrastructure or risk (depending on your career trajectory) first.